# What do people eat, if not rice?

Tags: koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

Episode 7 of *Koutetsujou no Kabaneri* brings up the point that nobody in Japan eats rice anymore, since the rice paddies are outside the stations, and hence overrun by the *kabane*.

This makes a lot of sense, and is a splendid bit of worldbuilding. But if they can't grow rice, what staple food(s) do they grow and eat instead?

---

Out of all the common staple foods currently eaten, it seems that potatoes (or sweet potatoes) can provide the most calories-per-unit-area, clocking in at about 4-5 times as much as rice. But at just 4-5 times rice's calorie/area yield, they'd have to have lost no more than 75-80% of their arable land to maintain the same calorie output. Judging from the sizes of the stations we've seen, it doesn't seem plausible that they still have that much arable land - we see the railforts driving through days of outside-station land between stations.

Perhaps the resolution here is that Japan's population has dipped so precipitously in the face of the *kabane* menace that the meager amount of land enclosed by the stations does suffice to grow enough of some other staple crop to feed the people?

Comment: bread,corn,potato,cassava,meat,yam or other alternative  :v

Comment: @NamikazeSheena all this things need considerably big area to cultivate, especially to supply stations, which are really big. And free area for stations is really limited. Question was - how they handle it (if they do).

Comment: somebody in the art team did not get the message becasue the images of aragane station shows what look suspiciously like rice fields inside the walls.  http://koutetsujou-no-kabaneri.wikia.com/wiki/Aragane_Station?file=Aragane_Station_walls.png

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, I am thinking in terms of Japan, if not a manga/anime world.

Did you forget to think of seafood? Seafood is a big delicacy in Japan, considering all of Japan is surrounded by water. Although they must be careful not to over-fish.

[Reference](https://www.quora.com/Do-people-in-Japan-really-eat-as-much-fish-and-seafood-as-I-see-in-a-restaurant-menu)